# How do I put text and ruby code from link_to on the same line in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to put a `link_to` between `(` and `)` by doing this:

```
= div_for review do
    = link_to review.title, review_path(review)
    (
    = link_to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)
    )
```

The outcome is not what I want because it puts spaces between the parenthesis and the link text, so it looks like:

```
 link1 ( link2 )
```

But I want it to look like:

```
 link1 (link2)
```

How do I do that using haml?

Comment: Can you add the HTML you want generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a string with inline ruby:

```
= link_to review.title, review_path(review)
=raw "(#{link_to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)})"
```

The raw is for Rails 3 (and higher) only.

Comment: okay this worked...what does "raw" mean and why does this work?

Comment: In Rails 3, all strings are by default HTML-escaped (what used to require the h function in Rails 2). raw prevents this, so you get <a href... instead of &lt;a href=...

Comment: can I create a string of html from the helper in a controller?  string = raw ("#{link_to}") to get string = <a href=></a>?

Answer (score 5):

I recently fount interesting thing about haml

== - Ruby interpolated string

```
%h1== (#{link-to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)})
```

is like

```
%h1= raw "(#{link_to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)})"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
= link_to review.title, review_path(review)
= surround '(', ')' do
  = link_to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)
```

Alternatively, you could put your link in a `span` tag and tell Haml to eat the whitespace:

```
(
%span>= link_to review.user.email, user_path(review.user)
)
```